# Getting js to distinguish between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of creating a javascript application that is a to-do list where a user would enter a task, it appears on a list below where they could re-order tasks or check tasks off. One problem I've run into is that I'd like to have each task div that is created have a different background-color. As is I have it so that the list as a whole changes background color, but not each task separately ( I do understand why that is) I was wondering if someone had an easy solution to get so that each task added has a different background color (or alternating between the colors I have in my RandomColor function.) Below are the relevant code snippets.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tbtask').focus();
    $('#btnaddtask').button();
    $('#tbTask').addClass("ui-corner-all");
    $(document)

    .on('click', '#btnaddtask', function () {
        var newTask = $('#tbTask').val();

        if (newTask == "") {
            alert("Please enter a task!");
        }

        if (newTask) {
            RandomColor();
            $('#tasklist').append('<div class="taskdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="task" 
value="' + newTask + '" />' + newTask + '</div>');

        }
        $('#tbtask').val("").focus();
    })

function RandomColor() {
    var color = '#';
    var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
      document.getElementById('tasklist').style.background = color;
     }
```

Comment: Your methodology is a possible way to solve this.  Is it not selecting a random color now with what you have?  What is the problem?

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is selecting a random color for the **entire** list as a whole, however I wish to have is so that **each item** on the list gets a random background color.

Comment: you commented to the wrong person

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tbtask').focus();
    $('#btnaddtask').button();
    $('#tbTask').addClass("ui-corner-all");
    $(document).on('click', '#btnaddtask', function () {
        var newTask = $('#tbTask').val();

        if (newTask == "") {
            alert("Please enter a task!");
        }

        if (newTask) {
            $('#tasklist').append('<div class="taskdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="task" value="' + newTask + '" />' + newTask + '</div>');
            $('#tasklist .taskdiv:nth-last-child(1)').css('background-color', RandomColor());
        }
        $('#tbtask').val("").focus();
    });

function RandomColor() {
    var color = '#';
    var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];

    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Paul has the right idea.  You want to return a color from the RandomColor (which I rename to getRandomColor as I believe functions should be verbs) and style the new list item with that color before you insert it into the list.  Here's a similar answer, but cleaned up a bit (IMO):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // protip: cache this object, so you don't have to keep searching the DOM
    var $tbtask = $('#tbtask');

    $tbtask.focus();
    $tbtask.addClass("ui-corner-all");

    $('#btnaddtask').button();

    $(document).on('click', '#btnaddtask', function () {
        var newTask = $('#tbTask').val();

        if (!newTask) {
            alert("Please enter a task!");
        } else {

            // create a variable that stores the new DOM element
            var $newListItem = $(
                '<div class="taskdiv">' + 
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="task" value="' + newTask + '" />' + 
                    newTask + 
                '</div>'
            );

            // Assign a new color to the newly created list item before we insert it into the DOM
            $newListItem.css('backgroundColor', getRandomColor());

            // Insert our colorful list item into the list
            $('#tasklist').append($newListItem);

        }
        $tbtask.val("").focus();
    });

    function getRandomColor() {
        var color = '#';
        var letters =['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];

        return color;
    }
});
```